# How to detect in didFailWithError was called due to not having connection?

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

Is there a way I can tell when the reason why my Restkit didFailWithError function is called is the lack of connection to the server?

```
-(void) objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

//What should I do here to know the server could not be reached?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `NSURLConnection` `didFailWithError` method I use this code, it may apply to `RESTKit`, but I'm not sure.  I thought I would post this so you could at least check (it may help) :)

```
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed! Error code: %d - %@ %@", error.code, error.localizedDescription, [error.userInfo objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]]);

    if (error.code == -1009)
    {
        // This is the case that a connection failed based on bad connectivity
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Than you very much for your answer, but when I log the error.code without internet connectivity the console prints "2"... so I guess Restkit uses different codes...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take a look at the `NSError` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Where you will find the following relevant methods:

```
-(NSUInteger)code;

//A string containing the localized description of the error.
-(NSString *)localizedDescription;
```

So you would be checking the return value of this methods from the `NSError` you are receiving.